# Ubuntu on external HDD accessed from mac and windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows, mac, external-hdd

I have an external 2T HDD, an iMac intel, a windows laptop and a router (Airport Extreme). I'd like to install ubuntu on the ext HDD and have access to it either from the iMac or windows machine (locally).

I have read many posts here and on LifeHackers about dual/triple booting in the same machine, but I want to double boot from each machine being ubuntu in the same ext HDD.

Is that possible? Do I just need to follow the install instructions to dual boot for each machine/OS but targeting the same ext HDD? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to perform a completely normal install of Ubuntu to the external hdd, making sure to install grub (boot loader) on that harddisk and not your primary disk. Then you'll use the bios to choose which disk to boot from at startup.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do that and post back to share my findings.