# Bootable Ubuntu install on external drive for Mac *and* PC

Tags: boot, hard-drive, mac

I would like to install Ubuntu on an external drive that is bootable from *both* MAC and PC platforms.

A similar question was raised here but remained unverified: [Ubuntu on external HDD accessed from mac and windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320110/ubuntu-on-external-hdd-accessed-from-mac-and-windows)

Any thoughts on this would be most welcome.

Best,
Ruud

Answer (score 0):

Okay I installed Ubuntu on an external drive and booted it simply by in stalling rEFIT on my Mac. It probably also boots on my PC, since I did a full normal install on the drive without further modifications.